# Creating clickable link/url when posting on instagram using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I have a script that posts images with captions on Instagram programmatically using Google Apps Script. In the caption, when I add a link, it just posts it as simple text rather than a clickable URL. Here is the code:

```
function instapost() {
  const access_token = '########....######';
  const instagram_business_account = '########';

  const image = Drive.Files.get("1SNy876_kwrFBUCZdGfPLaKx6ZdKtYwn0").thumbnailLink.replace(/\=s.+/, "=s1000");
  const text = 'Hi, Click on this link to read the full article: https://www.google.com';
    var formData = {
    'image_url': image,
    'caption': text,
    'access_token': access_token
  };
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'payload' : formData
  };
  const container = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/' + instagram_business_account + '/media';
  // return;
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(container, options);

  const creation = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(creation);
  var creationId = data.id
  var formDataPublish = {
      'creation_id': creationId,
      'access_token': access_token
  };
  var optionsPublish = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'payload' : formDataPublish
  };
  const sendinstagram = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/' + instagram_business_account + '/media_publish';
  
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(sendinstagram, optionsPublish);
}
```

When I run this script, it creates an image post like this:

[image: InstaPost]

In the above screenshot, you can see that caption is just normal text. However, I want `https://www.google.com` to be clickable like this:

> https://www.google.com

rather than just a simple text. I am hoping that we need to make some changes in the following lines in `caption` parameter:

```
var formData = {
    'image_url': image,
    'caption': text,
    'access_token': access_token
  };
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an issue with your code; Instagram doesn't allow links in descriptions or comments. This is the same from the Web and Mobile UIs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. yeah, you are right about it. I thought there could be a way to achieve it programmatically.